# How can I get the variable in this axios Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Hi I have this code in Vuejs:

```
forceFileDownload(response, id) {
   axios.get('/api/documentation/'+ id +'/edit?api_token='+App.apiToken)
  .then(response => {
      this.documentation_data = response.data.data;
   });
   console.log(this.documentation_data);
   const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]))
   const link = document.createElement('a')
   link.href = url
   link.setAttribute('download', 'movement.pdf')
   document.body.appendChild(link)
   link.click()
  },
```

I want to get the this.documentation_data from the axios above, how can I do that? because it says undefined.. and there is data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because the execution of `axios.get` is not done when you're trying to populate your own data with its data.

Make your method async, then wait for the execution of Axios to be completed.

```
async forceFileDownload(response, id) {
   await axios.get('/api/documentation/'+ id +'/edit?api_token='+App.apiToken)
  .then(response => {
      this.documentation_data = response.data.data;
   });
   console.log(this.documentation_data);
   const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]))
   const link = document.createElement('a')
   link.href = url
   link.setAttribute('download', 'movement.pdf')
   document.body.appendChild(link)
   link.click()
  },
```

Comment: TY!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!